# Slow radix sort in C

Tags: c, sorting, radix

I have to sort numbers in array in ascending order and my time complexity has to be O(n). I'm using radix sort and it's not fast enough. Any ideas how could i make my code faster? Here it is:

```
void radix(int *a, int n) { 

    int i;
    int sorted[n];
    int number = 1;
    int biggestNumber = -1;

 for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
     if(a[i] > biggestNumber)
        biggestNumber = a[i]; }


while (biggestNumber / number > 0){

 int bucket[10] = { 0 };

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      bucket[(a[i] / number) % 10]++;

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      bucket[i] += bucket[i - 1];

    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      sorted[--bucket[(a[i] / number) % 10]] = a[i];


   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      a[i] = sorted[i];

      number*= 10; } }
```

Comment: Do the function work? Then you should post on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: Are you asking how to speed up your existing code, or are you asking after a more efficient sort algorithm?

Comment: What do you mean by "not fast enough"? Is it like some online excercise with time limit, or how do you define "fast enough"?

Comment: The only O(n) sorting algorithm is the [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) and that's only O(n) if the array entries are in the range 0 to `n` (or some small multiple of `n`).

Comment: @user3386109, radix sort is `O(w * n)` for `n` keys of size `w`.  If you consider `w` a constant, then `O(w * n)` = `O(n)`.  In particular, it is appropriate to consider `w` constant in the context of sorting keys of a specific data type.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't consider `w` a constant. If `n` is the number of elements in the array, and `k` is the largest element in the array, then the counting sort is `O(n+k)` and a radix sort is `O(n logk)`. Every other analysis is just marketing BS.

Comment: @user3386109, "marketing BS" seems a bit strong.  To be sure, if the question is about efficiency in an abstract sense, then you're quite right, but if it is about sorting data *of a particular fixed-width type*, then `k` is bounded and hence `O(n logk)` = `O(n)`.  This is not marketing, it's math.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But then we get to the degenerate case where every algorithm running on real hardware is O(1), because even `n` is a constant. So the fallacy in your position is that you don't recognize the limit on `n`, but you are placing a limit on `k`. As an example, given 64-bit numbers on a machine with 4GB of memory, the limit on `n` is in fact much tighter than the limit on `k`.

Comment: @user3386109, in analyzing a given problem, it is indeed appropriate to consider whether our assumptions are reasonable -- for example, that `n` can become large enough to see the effect of the asymptotic limits of various candidate algorithms.  For this particular case, however, note that: (1) bounded k is the typical real-world case; (2) with external storage, n can be almost arbitrarily large; and (3) for the sort in question, we care not about the limit on `k` but about the limit on `logk`, which is much smaller than the limit on n.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I see, so if my algorithm is `O(VlogE)`, then I care not about `E` because `logE` is much smaller than `V` on any real hardware. Or taking a different tack, `k` can be almost arbitrarily large if you sort arbitrary precision numbers, or if you sort strings using radix-256 or radix-16.

Comment: @user3386109, asymptotic performance analysis is not about algorithm advocacy or marketing, it is about choosing a suitable algorithm for a given purpose.  It is therefore entirely appropriate to apply it to important subsets of more general problems, and sorting keys of a specific fixed width is a class of such subsets.  For many of the most interesting of those subsets, radix sort is well-characterized as O(n), and if I'm trying to choose an algorithm for one of those problems then how that algorithm performs for different problems just doesn't matter.

Comment: *"choosing a suitable algorithm for a given purpose"* Exactly, on that we agree. The difference between an engineer and an academic is that the engineer makes that choice based on the actual running time on real hardware for real values of `n` and `k`, and doesn't give a damn about asymptotic performance on imaginary machines with unlimited external storage.

Comment: @JohnBollinger To put it another way, if big-O notation doesn't allow one to make the right decisions in real world situations, then big-O notation is worthless. Ignoring constant factors is not a luxury you have in the real world. And pretending that `k` doesn't affect the running time of the code is also not useful. The running time of a counting sort is proportional to `n+k`. The running time of a radix sort is proportional to `n logk`. If you ignore the value of `k`, you cannot make the right choice between those two algorithms.

Comment: @user3386109, you're right: asymptotic complexity analysis does not distinguish between radix sort and counting sort for keys of any given fixed width.  It does not do so whether you spell both complexities `O(n)` or whether you spell one `O(n+k)` and the other `O(n logk)`.  But it *does* distinguish between either of those algorithms on one hand, and, say, any comparison sort on the other.  The answer to the question of which algorithm to choose does not by any means stop at asymptotic complexity, but it does *consider* asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Alright, we'll let it go at that. Enjoyed chatting with you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment - The sort appears to only work with positive numbers, if a[i] is negative, then a negative index is used for bucket[...] and sorted[...]. You could change this to sort unsigned integers if signed integers are not required. There's no check for overflow on number *= 10. sorted is being allocated from the stack, which won't work if n is large. Use malloc() to allocate space for sorted.

To make the sort faster:

Change the base of the radix from 10 to 256. To avoid possible overflow, check for 0 == (number *= 256) to break out of the loop.

Alternate the direction of the radix sort on each pass. 1st pass from a to sorted, next pass from sorted to a. This is easiest using a pair of pointers, that are swapped on each pass, then after sort is complete, checking to see if the sorted data ended up in a[] and if not, copy from sorted[] to a[].

Make bucket a matrix. Assuming ints are 32 bits, and the base is 256, then bucket would be [4][256]. This allows a single pass over a[] to create the bucket matrix. If ints are 64 bits, bucket would be [8][256].